# Merging is leaving column in python

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have used pandas to merge two data but it leaves a column

```
job_Req = job_Req.loc[:,['Job Requisition','Job Requisition ID','Job Requisition Filled Date','Job Requisition Completed','Target Hire Date']]

job_Req = job_Req.groupby(['Job Requisition ID','Job Requisition']).max()

df= pd.merge(SWRI, job_Req, how='left', left_on=['Job Requisition Id'], right_on=['Job Requisition ID'])
```

While merging it merges all the date fields with the main file and leaves the Id and Job Requisition.

The  date fields
(['Job Requisition Filled Date', 'Job Requisition Completed',
'Target Hire Date'],
gets added to SWRI Report from job_Req Dataframe but not the **Job Requisition** column.

I need to add the **Job Requisition** column also in SWRI report.

I observed that on grouping it showing only all the Date Field column.

do I need to change the groupby code to get this corrected

Comment: Please post the output you get and the desired output. Your question is unclear at this moment.

Comment: I really didn't get what you want, but I think this can be done by [`pd.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Comment: Checkout using right_index=True or left_index=True parameter in your merge.